# Dovecot: doveadm move command syntax

Tags: dovecot, imap

I want to transfer an email from user1@domain.com to put it in a folder of another user: user2@domain.com

For that, it seems to me appropriate to use 'doveadm move' command, but I can not get the right result. Can you help me?

syntax:
    doveadm move [-u |-A] [-S ]  [user ]

my attempts:

```
doveadm move -u user2@domain.com DIRECTORY_2 mailbox user1@domain.com:'DIRECTORY_1' all
```

return: **Error: Syncing mailbox user1@domaine.fr:DOSSIER_1 failed: Mailbox doesn't exist: user1@domaine.fr:DOSSIER_1**

```
doveadm -u user2@domain.com DIRECTORY_2 mailbox sdbox:/complete/path/user1@domain.com/mailboxes/DIRECTORY_1 all
```

return: **Error: Syncing mailbox sdbox:/complete/path/user1@domain.com/mailboxes/DIRECTORY_1 failed: Mailbox doesn't exist: sdbox:/complete/path/user1@domain.com/mailboxes/DIRECTORY_1**

```
doveadm move -u user2@domain.com DIRECTORY_2 mailbox user1@domain.com 'DIRECTORY_2' all
```

return: **Fatal: Unknown argument DIRECTORY_2**

*some details:*

- directory exists
- the following command works (in case 'DIRECTORY_1' and 'DIRECTORY_2' are in the user1@domain.com user):
  doveadm move -u user1@domain.com DIRECTORY_2 mailbox 'DIRECTORY_1' ALL
- my problem is that I can not put another user destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution:

```
doveadm move -u user2@domain.com DIRECTORY_2 user user1@domain.com mailbox DIRECTORY_1 ALL
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`doveadm [-Dv] move [-S socket_path] -u user destination search_query`

You need 3 things.

1. The destination folder has to exist, does it? It should usually be under the same directory.
2. `ALL` needs to be all caps.
3. Is `DIRECTORY_2` the destination, or the second path?

Assuming `DIRECTORY_2` is the place where you want to put it (and it exists):

`doveadm move -u user2@domain.com DIRECTORY_2 ALL`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question with what you ask.